# how to (definitely) remove 1 row out of my dataset in R

Tags: r, row

I just started working with R for my master's thesis and I don't know anything about it, except that I'm very happy when it runs smoothly without any errors.

My question is this:
I have a dataset with all kinds of information about 66 families. I decided to make a case study (with family number 31), so I'm going to compare this #31 to the rest of the families. For this, I need to exclude the row where all the information about #31 is stored (I can't compare it to itself). Thus, I should create a dataset with only 65 families, without family 31.

I already searched for ways to do this on this site.

- simply adding `[-31]` at the end while doing an analysis does not seem to change anything about my results, so I'm guessing this is wrong.
- I tried doing

  ```
  >NSG$id_O [31] <- NA 
  >NSG$id_P [31] <- NA
  >NSG$id_K1 [31] <- NA 
  >NSG$id_K2 [31] <- NA
  ```

  but this does not seem right. (`NSG` is the name of the dataset, `id_O` is the parent's identification number in this dataset; `P` stands for Partner; `K1` for child one and `K2` for second child). I want to remove it, not `NA` it.
- same thing with `<- NULL`

  ```
  >NSG$id_O [31] <- NULL
  ```

I'm terribly sorry if this is a stupid question (it probably is)! I'm just losing a lot of time trying to do this simple task and it's really bothering me.

Comment: `NSG <- NSG[-31, ]`  You need the `,` to signify that you are selecting all columns.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `[-31]` returns an object without row 31, but doesn't modify the original.

You want to do something like this:

```
NSG = NSG[-31,]
```

Comment: That's removing column 31

Comment: Right - misplaced comma =/

Answer (score 0):

I would make two data sets to run analysis with something like:

```
case<-x[31,]
test<-rbind(x[1:30,],x[32:66,])
```

Now you can run whatever analysis you'd like on either of the sets or compare summary statistics to the case set.